# BeautifulSoup + URLLib2 not extracting all of the XML from target

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288776/000119312512312575/goog-20120630.xml"

req = urllib2.Request(url, "r")
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
xml = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, features="xml")
print soup.prettify()
```

The output only displays the first few lines of XML from the target:

```
>>> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- EDGAR Online I-Metrix Xcelerate Instance Document, based on XBRL 2.1  http://www.edgar-online.com/ -->
<!-- Version:  6.17.6 -->
<!-- Round: 8321e8af-cc4a-498e-a38d-da694ed77a41 -->
<!-- Creation date: 2012-07-24T16:17:46Z -->
<xbrl xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:country="http://xbr" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:xbrll="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Any ideas how to extract all of the XML?

Comment: OP - if you have found a solution you can answer your own question, or if you used mine you can mark it as accepted. are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using an opener?

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288776/000119312512312575/goog-20120630.xml"

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]  
resource = opener.open(url)
data = resource.read()
resource.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.prettify()
```

above code works for me.

Comment: i would like to note however, this took a while to run, about a minute or so. lots of data.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just ran into this myself, but after I fetched the full SGML document from the SEC website via FTP, and read it from disk.  I had:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xbrl, ["lxml", "xml"])
```

I changed it to:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xbrl, "lxml")
```

... and then I was able to get all of the XML.  I believe your problem might be the additional 'features="xml"' code in the BeautifulSoup function call?  That's consistent with Inbar Rose's answer, which does not have any additional arguments to the BeautifulSoup() function call.

Good luck!